# What is the name of this decorator/handler chain implemented using iteration?

Tags: design-patterns, decorator, middleware

I have a design pattern which has commonalities and differences with the following:

- The decorator pattern is built on composition, where each decorator has a reference to the next decorator in the chain.
- The middleware pattern moves knowledge of the next handler outside of the handlers themselves, providing a next method.
- Chain of Responsibility is more like the middleware pattern, except only one handler chooses to take an action and the chain is terminated.

In contrast with the above, my design pattern does not rely on recursion or nested composition, and does not have a `next` method.

- A list of handlers are called in order by a "Sequence Controller"
- Each handler takes X as an argument, then provides a new value for X.
- Any number of handlers might perform an action

So there's a controller that handles the sequencing - you could stop or pause the sequence from somewhere outside while it's running (including one of the handlers, if it is a handler that happens to be aware of the sequence controller), unlike with the decorator or middleware patterns.

This pattern seems very useful because it keeps handlers generic (Sequence Controller is one of many possible strategies for executing the handlers), and does not increase the size of the call stack.

I would like to know is if this design pattern has been described before and already has a name and terminology to go with it. (for example I call these handlers but maybe they're called "Invokable" or "Step")

Comment: Can you link to a reference for "the middleware pattern"? I'm curious whether that's formally defined. It's not a GoF pattern.

Comment: Feel free to ask any question. If you feel that my reply is helpful, then you can upvote or mark my reply as an answer to simplify the future search of other users. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309682)

Comment: I've been using StackOverflow for years, I just haven't used it the "right way" to get the gold a silver circles that make people believe I know what I'm doing. Your answer is describing a design pattern unrelated to my question.

Answer (score 0):

> There's a controller that handles the **sequencing** - you could stop or
> pause the sequence from somewhere outside while it's running
> (including one of the handlers,

If you have skeleton of an operation in terms of a number of high-level steps, then it can be some Template method pattern.

As wiki says about [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

> The template method is a method in a superclass, usually an abstract
> superclass, and defines the skeleton of an operation in terms of a
> number of high-level steps. These steps are themselves implemented by
> additional helper methods in the same class as the template method.